# Packaging New Software on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, packaging

My goal is to learn the correct and current process for packaging software on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I am following the [Packaging guide for Ubuntu](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/).

The documentation section "[Starting a Package](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html#starting-a-package)" (4.2) states:

```
unfortunately the bzr dh-make subcommand is no longer available in releases later than
Ubuntu 20.04; so, you might need a container or virtual machine (see LXD) running
Ubuntu 20.04 for this particular step.
```

Is there documentation of the process that should be used in 22.04 to package software? This guide has a dependency on an old version of Ubuntu and commands that are no longer available.

Comment: the guide literally says to use a container and links to [LXD](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/).

Comment: @Esther nevertheless, the question seems valid. The question's implication that running a 20.04 VM or container seems a klunky workaround is on-target.

Comment: Since that guide was written, the world has continued to change. It's unclear if you are learning to package specifically for contribution to Ubuntu, or if you are learning to package for your own PPA. It's also unclear if you are specifically tied to the deb format or if you are open to other alternatives. Currently (2022), the *best* way to learn deb packaging is at http://mentors.debian.net, as Debian is actively recruiting and training package maintainers...and those packages sync to Ubuntu.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to maintain my own PPA. But I am just starting this process. I want to first understand the very basics of the process of building a deb package using the current and correct process on 22.04. The packaging guide that I linked to seems straightforward, but it is outdated because it is tied to an old version of Ubuntu. Is there somewhere that I can read about the current process? I do see the mentor program and I appreciate the recommendation, but I don't want to burden that mentor program or the people involved there.

Comment: What I'd like is to be pointed to a document that is similar to the one in the packaging guide that covers the current process.